Search Bar makes the CPU GO OVER 100% ON iOS - flutter app
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'; // Import for Firebase Storage
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'media_page.dart';
import 'expozanti_page_display.dart';
import 'conferinte_page.dart';
import 'conferinte_page_display.dart';

class SearchBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBarPage({super.key});

  @override
  SearchBarPageState createState() => SearchBarPageState();
}

class SearchBarPageState extends State<SearchBarPage> {
  String _searchQuery = '';
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _searchResults = [];
  String _selectedCategory = 'Exhibitors';
  final Map<String, Future<String>> _imageFutureCache = {};

  void _search(String query) async {
    setState(() {
      _searchResults = [];
    });

    final results = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(_selectedCategory.toLowerCase()).get();

    final filteredResults = results.docs.where((doc) {
      final data = doc.data();
      final name = data['name']?.toString().toLowerCase() ?? '';
      return name.contains(query.toLowerCase());
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      _searchResults = filteredResults;
    });
  }

  Future<String> _getImageUrl(String exhibitorName) {
    if (_imageFutureCache.containsKey(exhibitorName)) {
      return _imageFutureCache[exhibitorName]!;
    }

    Future<String> imageUrlFuture = _fetchImageUrl(exhibitorName);
    _imageFutureCache[exhibitorName] = imageUrlFuture;
    return imageUrlFuture;
  }

  Future<String> _fetchImageUrl(String exhibitorName) async {
    try {
      return await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('stand_logos/$exhibitorName.png')
          .getDownloadURL();
    } catch (_) {
      try {
        return await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref('stand_logos/$exhibitorName.jpg')
            .getDownloadURL();
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("Error fetching image: $e");
        return 'assets/avatar_icon.png';
      }
    }
  }

  void _navigateToExpozantiPageDisplay(Map<String, dynamic> exhibitorData) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ExpozantiPageDisplay(
          name: exhibitorData['name'] ?? 'N/A',
          phone: exhibitorData['phone'] ?? 'N/A',
          country: exhibitorData['country'] ?? 'N/A',
          email: exhibitorData['email'] ?? 'N/A',
          web: exhibitorData['web'] ?? 'N/A',
          facebook: exhibitorData['facebook'] ?? 'N/A',
          instagram: exhibitorData['instagram'] ?? 'N/A',
          linkedin: exhibitorData['linkedin'] ?? 'N/A',
          stand: exhibitorData['stand'] ?? 'N/A',
          location: exhibitorData['location'] ?? 'N/A',
          fairName: exhibitorData['fair'] ?? 'N/A',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToMediaPage(Map<String, dynamic> mediaData) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MediaPage(mediaData: mediaData, isSingleView: true),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToConferintePageDisplay(Map<String, dynamic> conferenceData) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ConferintePageDisplay(conference: Conference.fromMap(conferenceData)),
      ),
    );
  }

  String toTitleCase(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty) return text;
    return text
        .split(' ')
        .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase())
        .join(' ');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Search', style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search...',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _searchQuery = value;
                          });
                          _search(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Wrap(
                spacing: 8.0,
                children: [
                  _buildCategoryBubble('Exhibitors'),
                  _buildCategoryBubble('Media'),
                  _buildCategoryBubble('Conferences'),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              _buildSearchResults(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoryBubble(String category) {
    bool isSelected = _selectedCategory == category;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedCategory = category;
          _search(_searchQuery);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0) : Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Text(
          category,
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
            color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchResults() {
    if (_searchQuery.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text('Enter a search term to begin.', style: GoogleFonts.montserrat()));
    } else if (_searchResults.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text('No results found.', style: GoogleFonts.montserrat()));
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _searchResults.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var data = _searchResults[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var name = toTitleCase(data['name'] ?? 'N/A');
          return ListTile(
            leading: FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _getImageUrl(data['name'] ?? 'N/A'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == 'assets/avatar_icon.png') {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/avatar_icon.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Image.network(
                        snapshot.data!,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            title: Text(name, style: GoogleFonts.montserrat()),
            subtitle: Text(_selectedCategory == 'Exhibitors'
                ? 'Location: ${data['location'] ?? 'N/A'} | Stand: ${data['stand'] ?? 'N/A'}'
                : _selectedCategory == 'Media'
                    ? 'Tag: ${data['tag'] ?? 'N/A'}'
                    : 'Date: ${DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format((data['start_time'] as Timestamp).toDate())}'),
            onTap: () {
              if (_selectedCategory == 'Exhibitors') {
                _navigateToExpozantiPageDisplay(data);
              } else if (_selectedCategory == 'Media') {
                _navigateToMediaPage(data);
              } else {
                _navigateToConferintePageDisplay(data);
              }
            },
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}

I develop an app where the search bar makes the CPU go over 100% on iOS resulting in all of the pictures from storage load much slower. I receive this error '[firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference' that increments going to 1000 errors. I assume that this happens because I didn't optimize the retrieval of images from Firebase Storage. This happens to every search bar that I implemented on the app. I search for something, I press on a result, I am redirected to the the result page, when I press back that error begins to increment and making the CPU go over 100%.
On android the code work perfectly.
